# c# Regex catch string between two string

Tags: c#, html, regex, match

i've to catch a value beetween angular brackets, I parse an'html page into a string (i can't use external library, so i have to use that html like a string). I have two div's content to catch, i know the id they have and i'm trying to catch the content by using regex, but i'm not able to do it.

`var div_tags = Regex.Match(json, "<div id=(.*)</div>").Groups[0];`

that returns me all the 3 div that i have with an id. but i only need of two div, wich id contains the word "mobile".
So.. I tryed another regex suggested by a my coworker, but if think that it's not compatible with .net regex evaluetor.

`string titolo = Regex.Replace(json, "<div id=[.*]mobile[.*]>(.*)</div>");`

Thath's an example of the div. the only value i need is Message. The two div's ids are mobileBody and mobileTitle.

`<div id='mobileBody' style='display:none;'>Message</div>`

What's wrong in my regex that doesn't allow me to catch the correct text?

Comment: Use an html parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex). Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: You should use an HTML parser.

Comment: I said that i can't use an external library, so i can't use HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: noone knows, how adjust the regex expression for matching what i need

Comment: You can use an external library.

Comment: i can't use external library...

Comment: Why can't you use external library? Parsing HTML using Regex is virtually certain to be error-prone.

Comment: because is an enterprise mobile application, and we'rent able to do what we want. so we can't do some stuff.

Comment: H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

Comment: `[ ]` in regex is very different from `( )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:
`<[a-z\s]+id=[\'\"]mobile[\w]+[\'\"][\sa-zA-Z\d\'\=\;\:]*>([a-zA-Z\d\s]+)<[\/a-z\s]+>` 
Anyway it will not match special chars or symbols. 
You can test and optimize it here: https://regex101.com/r/fnYQ1o/10

**EDIT - Code example** 
This could be the portion of code to extract the messages:

```
 var rgx = @"<[a-z\s]+id=[\']mobile[\w]+[\'][\sa-zA-Z\d\s\'\=\;\:]*>([a-zA-Z\d\s]+)<[\/a-z\s]+>";
 var txt = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='it' xml:lang='it'><!-- <![endif]--><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'><title>Banca Mediolanum S.p.A. | Accesso clienti</title><meta name='description' content='Banca Mediolanum S.p.A. | Accesso clienti'><meta name='keywords' content='Banca Mediolanum S.p.A. | Accesso clienti'><meta name='title' content='Banca Mediolanum S.p.A. | Accesso clienti'><meta name='author' content='Banca Mediolanum S.p.A.'><meta name='robots' content='index, follow'><meta name='viewport' content='width=1439,user-scalable=no'><link rel='shortcut icon' href='./images/favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'><style>#cort {background-image: url(bmedonline_10set.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position-x: center;height: 850px;width: auto;/*background-size: 100%;*/}@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 641px) section.contactus-area.chat {}body {border: 0 none;margin: 0;padding: 0}</style></head><body class=' '><!-- Google Tag Manager --><script>(function (w, d, s, l, i) {w[l] = w[l] || [];w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event: 'gtm.js'});var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j = d.createElement(s),dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';j.async = true;j.src ='//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);})(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-KGSP');</script><!-- End Google Tag Manager --><div id='cort'></div><div id='mobileTitle' style='display:none;'>Titolo prova</div><div id='mobileBody' style='display:none;'>Corpo messaggio prova</div></body></html>";

 /* Using matches and aggregation */
 var matches = Regex.Matches(txt, rgx).Cast<Match>();
 /* Aggregation without using foreach*/
 if (matches != null && matches.Count() > 0)
 {
    matches = matches.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Groups[1].Value));
    var exitString = matches.Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value).Aggregate((x, y) => x + "-" + y);
    Console.WriteLine("Match and aggregation");
    Console.WriteLine(exitString);
  }

  /* using replace with regex: .*<div id='mobileTitle'[\s\w\W]*>([\s\w]*)<\/div>[\s\r\n]*<div id='mobileBody'[\s\w\W]*>([\s\w]*)<\/div>.* */
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine(@"Replace with another regex");
  Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(txt, @".*<div id='mobileTitle'[\s\w\W]*>([\s\w]*)<\/div>[\s\r\n]*<div id='mobileBody'[\s\w\W]*>([\s\w]*)<\/div>.*", "$1-$2"));

  Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.
If before i use the method: Regex.Match(string, "your_regex");
i have error "unrecognized escape sequence". if i place a @ before your regex, the error are too.
how could i remove the error?

Comment: i don't know why, but it also doesn't work.
I did like below:

var s = Regex.Matches(json, "<div id='mobile(.*?)</div>");
string titolo = s[0].ToString();
titolo = titolo.Substring(titolo.IndexOf(">")+1);
titolo = titolo.Substring(0, titolo.IndexOf("<"));
string body = s[1].ToString();
body = body.Substring(body.IndexOf(">")+1);
body = body.Substring(0, body.IndexOf("<"));

But if by regex i could take the body without doing string manipulation, it would be great

Comment: I added a working example in the edited post. It get only the text inside tags and if group 1 ([a-zA-Z\d\s]+) is not empty.

Comment: Oh, thank you.
This code got stuck in loop, i think it's because of the linq or somethink like it. Tryed on this site: http://rextester.com/
But when the loop is stopped, it give me the correct values. do you know where the errors are?

Comment: I've just paste the code to visual studio, and it works really fine. Maybe it use too much resourse for the online compiler..
By the way, could you explain me why you use the cast methods with empty () ? Doing that isn't like don't using it?

Comment: Because the method .Cast<TResult>() doesn't accept any input arguments. It is a extension method that simply "Casts the elements of an IEnumerable to the specified type". As you can see in this Microsoft reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: By the way, i just noticed that an online regex tester for c# make differents result instead of regex on c#,
Infact i made the right regex that i want, but running it, it would not give me the correct response.

http://regexstorm.net/tester
here i posted the regex and into the replacement i put "$1-$2", that gaves me the two string separated by a '-'. How could I reproduce it on c#? Using replace i receive a differnt match.

Comment: Is you code like this? var rgx = Regex(strRgx); rgx.Replace(input, "$1-$2");

Comment: yes, it's
var result = Regex.Replace(json, @"<div id='mobileTitle'[\s\w\W]*>([\s\w]*)</div><div id='mobileBody'[\s\w\W]*>([\s\w]*)</div>","$1-$2");
in json there's the html string.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the regex will not match if there is a carriage return or new line or a blank between those two divs. Without the "json" i can't say precisaly.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Nr6fPE22§
Here there is the "json" value.
i know it's not a json, but usually a json is stored into it. so the variable is named json.

Comment: The problem is that simply didn't match the whole string and replace only the matched one with the two groups: https://regex101.com/r/tVQFUZ/1. If you don't want to use the matches method you can add .* at the start and at the end of the regex: https://regex101.com/r/M3Cg0z/1. i will edit the answer with an example.

Comment: ohhhhw, finally. ".*" is what i was looking for. now it do the excact thing that i want.
Thank you very much :)